# How do I match any character across multiple lines in a regular expression for Atom Editor?

Tags: regex, xml, atom-editor

I wrote a RegEx to match any character across multiple lines between two tags in Atom.

This is my RegEx:

```
<column name=\"body\">([\s\S]*)<\/column>
```

This is the content of my file:

```
<column name="body">﻿Lorem ipsum dolor 1.
Si stante, hoc natura videlicet vult;
Est, ut dicis, inquam.</column>
<column name="body">﻿Lorem ipsum dolor 2.
Si stante, hoc natura videlicet vult;
Est, ut dicis, inquam.</column>
```

Unfortunately the RegEx matches everything. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: It is matching from the first column to the last. Does Atom support minimal matching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the "non-greedy" `?` quantifier, like this:

```
<column name=\"body\">([\s\S])*?<\/column>
```

It will make the `([\s\S])` capture group match as few times as possible.  Without the `?`, it will match as many as possible.